# what is the best way to use charts and gauge controls in wpf/c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, gauge

Are there any good libraries for charts and gauche controls (WPF/.net 4.5/C#)? I need them to embed into a windows application, which should run under windows embedded. probably windows embedded 8.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/charting-in-wpf/) tutorial demonstrates how to draw various charts including line chart, bar chart, column chart, area chart, scatter chart, and pie chart using WPF and C#.

And there is a

Free tools supporting panning / zooming:

- [DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) - a nice, open source data visualization
  library. Unfortunately it's not been updated since April 30, 2009.

Free tools without built in pan / zoom support:

- [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535). Supports most important 2D charts, you'll have to
  implement pan / zoom yourself.

And a

Paid tools with built in pan / zoom support:

- [Visiblox Charts.](http://www.visiblox.com/) Support for the most important 2D charts, comes with
  zooming and panning. The free version comes with watermark. ([See this
  blog post](http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2010/11/zooming-panning-in-silverlight-using-visiblox-charts) on using zooming / panning)
- [SciChart.](http://www.scichart.com/) Supports most important 2D charts, comes with zooming and
  panning, mouse-wheel with animation on zoom. ([See this blog post](http://www.scichart.com/synchronizing-chartmodifier-mouse-events-across-charts/) on
  using zooming / panning across multiple charts)
- [Infragistics xamDataChart.](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/data-visualization/xam-data-chart.aspx#Overview) Supports most important 2D charts, zooming
  and panning. [See this blog article](http://forums.infragistics.com/blogs/kiril_matev/archive/2010/04/20/a-fast-wpf-chart-featuring-zooming-panning-in-winforms.aspx) on how to use zooming.
- [Telerik RadChart.](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx?gclid=CMOpoaHD8pgCFQqF3goddzFT1w) Supports lots of 2D charts, has some support for
  zooming and panning, you might need to do a little work on that.
- [Visifire.](http://visifire.com/) Supports lots of 2D charts and zooming without animation,
  might need to do some extra work for smoother zooming.

Answer (score -1):

The [Dashboarding](http://dashboarding.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex is an implementation of gauge controls in WPF/Silverlight.  But you'd need to port to .NET 4.5.

Comment: This answer is more of a comment than an answer. Please provide some info that answers the questions. A link can be outdated anytime. Thanks